# FQL Request failed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm working with Facebook FQL request and i want to get my friends events so i'm using this request:

```
SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

This request worked a few days ago but it now i've got this error:

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request failed, because your query is too big for the FQL.

So break your query. First, get all the friends from -

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
```

then, for each friend uid, query-

```
SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 'FRIEND_ID'
```